Appending a .docx file to another .docx file in node
I have two files: doc1.docx and doc2.docx
Does anyone know how I can append doc2 to the end of doc1 programmatically? Imagine doc1 is a template front page and doc2 is a page of data. The end product should thus be mergeddoc.docx which looks like doc1 then doc2 aka front page on page 1 and data page on page 2. In word I guess you'd be using the insert tool to add in a document.
I feel like this shouldn't be hard but I've been banging my head against this problem for about three days. If it is a hard problem, does anyone know of a work around? I know you can do this sort of stuff in python but is that the best solution?
Thanks!
I've tried to use .docx but it's not got a merging function
"docx-merger" is basically unsupported and out of date  - won't run for this functionality unless I'm missing something
docx-templates doesn't work for me either no functionality.
Previous attempt example that doesn't work:
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const os = require("os");
const createReport = require("docx-templates").default;

const saveDocument = (buffer, patientData) => {
  try {
    const downloadsPath = path.join(os.homedir(), "Downloads");
    const filename = `Report_${patientData.forename}_${
      patientData.surname
    }_${Date.now()}.docx`;
    const filePath = path.join(downloadsPath, filename);

    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, buffer);

    return filePath;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in saveDocument:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

const generateDocument = async (data) => {
  try {
    console.log("Starting document generation...");

    const selectedGenes = data.selectedGenes;
    const geneData = data.geneData;
    const bloodResults = {
      testDetails: {
        lab: data.bloodsDetails.sendingApplication,
        receivedInLab: data.bloodsDetails.receivingFacility,
        patientId: data.bloodPatientID,
      },
      results: data.bloodResults,
    };
    const basicData = {
      patientData: data.patientData,
      clinician: data.clinicianIdentity,
    };
    const complaints = data.patientComplaints;
    const utilsData = {
      time: data.time,
      geneCount: data.selectedGenes.length,
      countBloodTests: data.bloodResults.length,
    };

    console.log("Data prepared:", {
      selectedGenes,
      geneData,
      bloodResults,
      basicData,
      complaints,
      utilsData,
    });

    const templatePath = path.join(
      __dirname,
      "../templates/base_template.docx"
    );

    if (!fs.existsSync(templatePath)) {
      throw new Error(`Template file not found at path: ${templatePath}`);
    }
    console.log(`Base template found at ${templatePath}`);

    const template = fs.readFileSync(templatePath);

    const dataForTemplate = {
      selectedGenes: [],
      geneData,
      bloodResults,
      basicData,
      complaints,
      utilsData,
    };

    for (const gene of selectedGenes) {
      const geneName = gene.geneName;
      console.log(`Processing gene: ${geneName}`);

      const geneTemplatePath = path.join(
        __dirname,
        "../templates/gene_templates",
        `${geneName}.docx`
      );

      if (!fs.existsSync(geneTemplatePath)) {
        throw new Error(
          `Gene template file not found for gene ${geneName} at path: ${geneTemplatePath}`
        );
      }
      console.log(`Gene template found at ${geneTemplatePath}`);

      const geneTemplateBuffer = fs.readFileSync(geneTemplatePath);

      dataForTemplate.selectedGenes.push({
        ...gene,
        genedoc: geneTemplateBuffer,
      });
    }

    console.log("Data prepared for main template:", dataForTemplate);

    // Generate the final report
    const buffer = await createReport({
      template,
      data: dataForTemplate,
      noSandbox: true, 
      additionalJsContext: {
        INS: (buffer) => ({
          _type: "rawXml",
          xml: buffer.toString("utf8"),
        }),
      },
    });

    console.log("Final report generated.");

    const filePath = saveDocument(buffer, data.patientData);

    console.log(`Document saved at ${filePath}`);

    return `Document generated successfully at ${filePath}`;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in generateDocument:", error);
    return `Error in generateDocument: ${error.message}`;
  }
};

module.exports = {
  generateDocument,
};

if (require.main === module) {
  (async () => {
    try {
      const data = {
        selectedGenes: [
          { geneName: "COMT", rsCode: "rs6311", combined: "TC" },
        ],
        geneData: {
          COMT: { description: "Catechol-O-methyltransferase gene" },
        },
        bloodsDetails: {
          sendingApplication: "Them",
          receivingFacility: "Us",
        },
        bloodPatientID: "123-4567",
        bloodResults: [
          {
            testCode: "HTR2A",
            testName: "HTR2A Test",
            value: "Positive",
            units: "blahs",
            referenceRange: "",
          },
        ],
        patientData: {
          patientId: "123-4567",
          title: "Mrs",
          forename: "Jane",
          surname: "Doe",
          dob: "1999-01-01",
          sex: "F",
        },
        clinicianIdentity: "Dr Who",
        patientComplaints: [
          "Decreased concentration",
          "Decreased mental sharpness",
        ],
        time: Date.now(),
      };
      const result = await generateDocument(data);
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        "Error running generateDocument from command line:",
        error
      );
    }
  })();
}

I've looked at other answers:
How to append docx file in Golang: wrong language
Using Node's 'Docx' to append to an existing Word doc with JS: explains a limitation in this particular packag
how to append a file using docx package: Same as above.
But I'm not seeing much action for alternate solution that allow this.

I think the best solution is to use another language like 'Python'.
To use this method, you need to install Python and find out the path to the executable file. (e.g. /usr/bin/python3 )
You can use this Python script (don't forget to install python docxcompose library with pip install docxcompose):
(./script.py)
from docxcompose.composer import Composer
from docx import Document
import sys

def main(argv):
    argsCount = len(argv)
    if argsCount < 2:
        print("pass 2 filenames: input, output")
        exit(1)
    inputPaths = argv[0:argsCount - 1]
    print("input paths:")
    print(inputPaths)
    outputPath = argv[argsCount - 1]
    print("output path:")
    print(outputPath)
    master = False
    composer = False
    for inputPath in inputPaths:
        if master == False:
            master = Document(inputPath)
            composer = Composer(master)
            print("composer created")
        else:
            doc = Document(inputPath)
            composer.append(doc)
    master.save(outputPath)
    exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])

And this js code
(./main.js)
import * as childProcess from 'child_process';
import * as path from 'path';
const execCmd = `/usr/bin/python3 ${path.join(__dirname,'script.py')} path_to_doc1.docx path_to_doc2.docx result_file_name.docx`
childProcess.execSync(execCmd);
// here you can access result_file_name.docx and delete path_to_doc1.docx, path_to_doc2.docx if you need

If you run this code using node main.js path_to_doc1.docx with path_to_doc2.docx will be merged into result_file_name.docx.
Then you can add python and docxcompose lib installation to dockerfile and use docker container.
In tests with documents totaling 150+ megabytes, this proved to be the fastest solution with the lowest RAM consumption.
